# Run AWS Lambda and SNS locally when Lambda is a container

Tags: aws-lambda, containers, .net-5, localstack

Since December 2020 AWS Lambda can run as a container https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/

I can now create AWS Lambda with .NET 5 and run it as a container https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-5-aws-lambda-support-with-container-images/

And I can even execute the AWS lambda containers locally with the Runtime Interface Emulator https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-test.html and POST events to a given local URL to trigger the lambda.

That's all great and reduces the pain I am suffering with local development of lambdas with C#.

I've discovered LocalStack which seems a great tool https://github.com/localstack/localstack which allows me to run SNS, SQS, Api Gateway and other services locally. It also have support for AWS Lambda, but I don't know how to deploy a lambda created as a container inside Localstack. I am starting to think that this is not possible.

Is it possible? If not, is there any workaround that allows me to locally have an SNS triggering my conteinerized Lambda? Or are all my options the following:

1. Not using local environment, test and develop against a real AWS account
2. Use .NET 3.1 instead of .NET 5, so that my AWS Lambda does not need to be containerized and, in theory, I can deploy it locally in LocalStack and integrate it with SNS

Comment: Don't think it's supported yet on localstack.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right, I've just read this: https://betterprogramming.pub/aws-lambda-now-supports-container-images-bff86b0f62b1 where it talks about the disadvantage of using containerized lambdas when relying on LocalStack.

Comment: The Localstack Pro seems to support lambda layers and lambda containers. Doesn't that mean that it can execute lambda as containers? Is it related to the lambda executor = docker environment variable that can be passed to localstack?